# django app on server: No module named 'django.urls'

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I have a `Django (v1.11.6)` app on my `Ubuntu` server and was using `Python v2.7`.

I am now using `Python 3.5` (not using `virtualenv`), however when I run `sudo service apache2` restart I get the following error in my browser:

```
ImportError at /
No module named 'django.urls'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://dev.ga.coach/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.urls'

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

When I run `python3 manage.py runserver` I get no error.

When I execute `sudo pip freeze | grep -i 'django'` I get the following:

```
Django==1.11.6
django-allauth==0.33.0
django-filter==1.0.4
django-rest-auth==0.9.1
djangorestframework==3.6.3
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
```

Comment: Again, you're using a different environment when running django (as can be seen by the fact you're actually using 1.8.7 not 1.11.6). You need to work out what environment your apache is running in

Comment: @Sayse You are right! How to change apache's django version?

Comment: Execute this command: `sudo pip freeze | grep -i 'django'` and post the output in your Q

Comment: @AbijithMg Thank you! I did it!

Comment: You need to look at your `httpd.conf` file and check what's set for `WSGIPythonHome`

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't have `https.conf`. I go to `apache2.conf` and I only have `WSGIPythonPath`.

Comment: and is that pointing to your new Python3.5 installation?

Comment: @dirkgroten That is pointing in my project actually. I will try to change it.

Comment: sorry my bad, should point to your project folder indeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157288/discussion-between-zinon-and-dirkgroten).

Comment: @dirkgroten OK, no problem. It didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache config is using Django 1.8.7 as you can see in your error. And you're using a newer method for including urls (`url(r'^users/', include('users.urls'), name='users')` inside `urls.py` which wasn't supported in Django 1.8.

Since your switched from python 2.7 to python 3.5 it's quite likely your `mod_wsgi` module is still the one compiled with python 2.7. Here's what the [WSGI docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#virtual-environment-and-python-version) say about that:

> When using a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi, it is very
>   important that it has been created using the same Python installation
>   that mod_wsgi was originally compiled for. It is not possible to use a
>   Python virtual environment to force mod_wsgi to use a different Python
>   version, or even a different Python installation.
>
> You cannot for example force mod_wsgi to use a Python virtual
>   environment created using Python 3.5 when mod_wsgi was originally
>   compiled for Python 2.7. This is because the Python library for the
>   Python installation it was originally compiled against is linked
>   directly into the mod_wsgi module. In other words, Python is embedded
>   within mod_wsgi. When mod_wsgi is used it does not run the command
>   line python program to run the interpreter and thus why you can’t
>   force it to use a different Python installation.

So try re-installing `mod_wsgi` using python 3.5. That should then be able to find the Django package you installed with python 3.5.

Comment: How to change django version in apache?

Comment: that's another question, there's multiple answers here on SO. It depends if you want to run it against a virtualenv or not. If not, just install the proper version of Django on your machine by running `pip install Django==1.11.6`. See the [Django docs on running Django with Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for more information.

Comment: I'm not using virtual env. I'm already having `django 1.11.6` installed. Previously I was using the `1.8.7`.

Comment: well it's obvious that either your apache config or your shell are running in a virtualenv, otherwise you wouldn't have two different version of django on the same machine. So check again.

Comment: Finally, I uninstalled both `django` versions and installed the newest and it's working!